# Philips 8 bit microcontrollers P83C524 - how to program?

Tags: microcontroller

I am trying to get some information whether there is a C/C++ compiler and how to program Philips P83C524 8 bit microcontroller, which burner to use(or perhaps any DIY burner recommendation).

Comment: I would be a link-only answer, so I'll just post here. The following link is available at the Keil supported NXP ICs and it seems to answer both questions: https://www.keil.com/dd/chip/3447.htm.

Comment: Before someone (not me today) writes a more extensive answer on how this is a 8051, how problematic that is for C++ execution, how limited the device is even for simple C, how it unlike less ancient alternatives has no debug, how you'd start by pulling the EA pin low, so you can program external memory instead of the little internal program memory, how commercial programmers for these dinosaurs get more expensive every year: you **are** asking this because you have a device with this chip that you need to change/repair, and a board respin to use a different MCU is out of the question, right?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, I have an ancient oil heater from Viessmann which has this MCU. Which however has some bugs. I would like to see if I can write my custom firmware for it.

Comment: @Pablo nice! So, first thing to check is whether there's a compatible memory chip nearby (and maybe EA being hardwired to ground)– it's not that uncommon for devices to go for external memory right away, since the MCU directly supports it. That would give you easiest access to what the CPU is executing, and you'd just need to find a programmer for the kind of memory (probably: an EEPROM), which might be easier (or cheaper if bought commercially). And: is the MCU socketed, or do you need to do in-system programming? (if it's socketed, you can guess my recommendation, though: replace with newer)